# Apollo client not updating cache

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to use the Apollo mutation component but somehow, my cache (or ui?) isn't updated as I expect. The code executes just fine, but the new user data received from the server (such as uuid/id etc.) has never been populated with the current one.

The 'updateCache' were I know about shouldn't be necessary for thus mutation as the returned fields of the query and mutation are both equal (?)

This is how my code look likes;

**Schema**

```
/**
 *
 * Reading user data from the cache
 */
export const GET_USER = gql`
   query getUser {
      user @client {
         uuid
         email
         firstName
         lastName
         __typename
      }
   }
`;

/**
 *
 * Sending user data to the GraphQL server
 */
export const SEND_USER = gql`
   mutation sendUser($input: UserInput!) {
      sendUser(input: $input) {
         uuid
         email
         firstName
         lastName
         __typename
      }
   }
`;
```

**Component**

```
return (
      <Mutation mutation={SEND_USER}>
         {(sendUser, { loading, data, error }) => (
            <Form handleOnSubmit={e => handleOnSubmit(e, sendUser)}>
               <UserFieldset user={userState} handleOnChange={handleOnChange} />
               <Button type="submit" loading={loading} disabled={loading}>
                  Create user
               </Button>

               <Query query={GET_USER}>
                  {({ data }) => (
                     <pre>
                        <h4>GET_USER</h4>
                        {JSON.stringify(data, null, 3)}
                     </pre>
                  )}
               </Query>

               <pre>
                  <h4>SEND_USER</h4>
                  {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
               </pre>

            </Form>
         )}
      </Mutation>
   );
};
```

Both queries above work just fine, I can receive the defaults I've set for the user with GET_USER and I can do a mutation by SEND_USER, the mutation is done, and some data returned is showed by my test dump. It seems also that the cache has been updated somehow in the good way, but has been overridden again by the default values, If the last item in the cache is the current one. See my screenshots;

**Screenshot of the initial state**

[image]

**Screenshot of the state after the mutation**
[image]

Comment: Why do we have `@client` directive against `user` field of getUser query? We use `@client` with apollo-link-state which is used to main local state. Try removing it and cache might get updated as expected.

Comment: @User97 Thank you for the comment. getUser was just to get the user state from the cache, this is why I added ```@client```. I didn't want to query the graphql server with the getUser query. Even when I remove the ```@client```, it's still not working as expected.

Comment: Ok, then maybe I misunderstood. If I understand it correctly now, user record is being saved in local cache without querying it from server and then when `sendUser` mutation is made, we are expecting user record in cache to be replaced by response of mutation. This won't happen since `id` of original user object saved in cache is `null` whereas its value is `1226` in response of mutation. Apollo client updates cache on the basis of `__typename` and `id` and since id is different here, it won't automatically update cache.

Comment: @User97 so how did you solve the issue?